# Dense output of SimMechanics?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have set up a model using SimMechanics. It outputs data at the times where the solver steps to. Is there any possibility to have some kind of dense output such that it is possible to interpolate these data to get the solution at arbitrary points without losing the high order of the integrator?
In Matlab this is easily possible using the function `deval` after the integration of one of the built-in ODE integrators.
In SimMechanics I can select these integrators, too. Is there some kind of analouge way to `deval`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, although it's a Simulink functionality, not specific to SimMechanics. In the Configuration Parameters of the model, you can set the model to `Produce Specified Output Only` (see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/gui/data-import-export-pane.html#bq9_fhw-1), under `Data Import/Export`. This way, only the outputs you specify will be produced regardless of the time steps taken by the solver.

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer my question because I asked for a way to have the solution at any time without having to run the simulation again if I choose an other set of times. Your answer is still helping me nevertheless.

Comment: @Wauzl Well, if you don't want to run the simulation again, you can (assuming that you have saved the simulation data to the workspace) always use functions like `interp1` to interpolate the simulation results and create additional points, as you would do with any standard MATLAB data, but my advice would be to re-run the simulation to generate exactly the data points you want. You may miss something (e.g. a resonance) by simply interpolating simulation data.

Comment: I’m aware of functions like `interp1` but due to the linear interpolation the order of the solution produced by it would drop to $\mathcal{O}(h_\mathsf{max})$. Nevertheless thanks for the hint :)

Comment: My mistake: Using linear interpolation the order of the solution drops to `O(hmax^2)`, of course.